# uknown protocol data error is thrown on running webdriver sampler in jmeter

Tags: performance, selenium-webdriver, jmeter

java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: data

following error is thrown on running webdriver sampler in jmeter, eventhough i am using right URL

I am trying to run payment ui application through jmeter using webdriver sampler , where url will be picked from the previous request, the following error is thrown,

Answer (score 0):

The URL needs to contain the protocol like [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP), [HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/HTTPS), [FTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/FTP), [FILE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme), etc.

If its a "payment", most probably the protocol is `https`

So double check the [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) which holds the URL from the previous request using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter) and if it doesn't start with `https` either amend the "previous" logic which extracts the URL or use string [concatenation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenation) to add construct the full [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) to the resource from the current URL and the relative URL path from the previous request.

Also be informed that using Selenium for performance testing is neither recommended by [Selenium developers](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/test_practices/discouraged/performance_testing/):

> Performance testing using Selenium and WebDriver is generally not advised. Not because it is incapable, but because it is not optimised for the job and you are unlikely to get good results.

nor by [WebDriver Sampler developers](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/):

> Note: It is NOT the intention of this project to replace the HTTP Samplers included in JMeter. Rather it is meant to compliment them by measuring the end user load time.